# Infinite sum of reciprocals of squares of lengths of tangents from origin to the curve $y=\sin x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form-expressions

This question is actually from [*MSE*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921750/infinite-sum-of-reciprocals-of-squares-of-lengths-of-tangents-from-origin-to-the). I had to post it here due to the lack of response there even after placing a bounty. Here goes the question

> Let tangents be drawn to the curve $y=\sin x$ from the origin. Let the points of contact of these tangents with the curve be $(x_k,y_k)$ where $x_k\gt 0 ;(k\ge 1)$ such that $x_k\in (\pi k,  (k+1)\pi)$ and $$a_k=\sqrt {x_k^2+y_k^2}$$ (Which is basically the distance between the corresponding point of contact and the origin i.e. the length of tangent from origin)  .

---

I wanted to know the value of

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{a_k ^2}$$

Now this question has just popped out in my brain and is not copied from any assignment or any book so I don't know whether it will finally reach a conclusion or not.

---

I tried writing the equation of tangent to this curve from origin and then finding the points of contact but did not get a proper result which just that the $x$ coordinates of the points of contact will be the positive solutions of the equation $\tan x=x$

On searching internet for sometime about the solutions of $\tan x=x$ I got two important properties of this equation.  If $(\lambda _n)_{n\in N}$ denote the roots of this equation then

> $$1)\sum_n^{\infty} \lambda _n \to \infty$$ $$2)\sum_n^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _n^2} =\frac {1}{10}$$

But were not of much help.

I also tried writing the points in polar coordinates to see if that could be of some help but I still failed miserably.

---

On trying a bit more using some coordinate geometry I found that the locus of the points of contact is $$x^2-y^2=x^2y^2$$

Hence for third sum we just need to find $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {\lambda _k ^2 +1}{\lambda _k ^2 (\lambda _k ^2 +2)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _k ^2} -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _k ^2 (\lambda _k ^2 +2)}=\frac {1}{10} -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _k ^2 (\lambda _k ^2 +2)}=\frac {1}{10} -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{2\lambda _k ^2} +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{2(\lambda _k ^2 +2)} =\frac {1}{20}+\frac {1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _k ^2 +2} 
 $$

Now for the second summation I did think about it to form a series but for the roots to be $\lambda _k^2 +2$ we just need to substitute $x\to \sqrt {x−2}$ in power series of $\frac {\sin x-x\cos x}{x^3}$ and then get the result but it was still a lot confusing for me.

Using $x\to\sqrt {x-2}$ in the above power series and using  [*Wolfram Alpha*](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power+series+of+%28sin+%28%E2%88%9A%28x-2%29%29-+%28%E2%88%9A%28x-2%29%29*cos+%28%E2%88%9A%28x-2%29%29%29%2F%28%E2%88%9A%28%28x-2%29%C2%B3%29%29) I have got a series. So we need ratio of coefficient of $x$ to the constant term so is the value of second summation equal to
$$\frac {5\sqrt 2\sinh(\sqrt 2)−6\cosh(\sqrt 2)}{4(2\cosh(\sqrt 2)−\sqrt 2\sinh(\sqrt 2))}?$$

Is this value correct or did I do it wrong?

I would also like to know if there is some other method to solve this problem

Comment: If $$\oint_{C(R)}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}g(z) dz$$ with the contour $C(R)$ a circle of radius $R$ with center the origin, tends to zero for $R\to\infty$, then the residue theorem (if applicable), yields a relation between the summation of $g(z)$ over the zeros of $f(z)$ in terms of the residues of the integrand at the poles of $g(z)$.

Comment: @Count Iblis: how is that related to the question?

Comment: Reading your title is an adventure.

Comment: @Qfwfq: The question can be posed as summing of $g(z)=\frac{1+z^2}{z^2(z^2+2)}$ over the zeros of $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)-z\cos(z)}{z^3}$, or alike. The hope is that under an appropriate choice of $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, one can use the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to evaluate the sum.

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be pointed out that the series $\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^3}$ comes from the [MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2921768), and as I understand the claim there this series equals $\frac{1}{3}\prod_{k\geq 1} (1-\frac{x^2}{\lambda_k^2})$. I have not verified this claim, but if it's true, then your approach does make sense. **UPD.** Precise argument can be seen in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84326).

I've also verified your analytical expression numerically, and it looks fine. Namely, the analytical expression gives $\sum_k a_k^{-2} = 0.0973745978\ldots$, while numerically we have $\sum_{k=1}^{10^5} \frac {\lambda _k ^2 +1}{\lambda _k ^2 (\lambda _k ^2 +2)} = 0.09737358469\ldots$ with the difference $\approx 10^{-6}$.

Answer (score 2):

One perhaps more direct way could be to use your expression $\frac {1}{20}+\frac {1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _k ^2 +2}$, expand it ($\frac {1}{20}+\frac {1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\lambda _k ^2} (1-\frac{2}{\lambda_k^2} + \cdots)$) and calculate this sum by using the sums-of-reciprocals of even powers of $\lambda_k$ which can be calculated in a simliar way as the sum of reciprocal squares of $\lambda_k$ (see the last sentence of the accepted answer of 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75206/sum-of-the-squares-of-the-reciprocals-of-the-fixed-points-of-the-tangent-functio).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the factorization argument! Although I doubt that computing sum of reciprocals of even powers of $\lambda_k$ based on Newton-Girard formulas is that simple, at least it's not simpler than using substitution $x\mapsto \sqrt{x-2}$.